# CSS/SCSS Code module not found in VSCode using relative path

Tags: css, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a SharePoint Framework web-part in VS Code.

Unfortunately my scss styles file cannot be found, even though it's in the same path - please see the image below:

[image]

I also checked the styles file `Events.module.scss` in case an error in their was preventing it being imported, but there are no issues with that file...

I have tried restarting VS Code...tried moving the files around, tried renaming the scss file...

So what is missing here, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Try refreshing the project folder structure, restarting VSCode.

Comment: might be helpful https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/146

Comment: @PriyeshKumar: Thanks, when I change the error line to `const styles = require('./Events.module.scss');` it works, but I get a suggestion to *Convert 'require' to 'import* ... very annoying

Comment: I found the solution at [How to use CSS Modules with TypeScript and webpack](https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10) - it's a bit of a faff or kerfuffle but it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at [How to use CSS Modules with TypeScript and webpack](https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10)

Either we can bypass the import by using `const s = require('./Button.css');`

or, install *Typings for CSS Modules* like so:

```
npm install --save-dev typings-for-css-modules-loader
```

then add the new rule to **webpack.config**:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'typings-for-css-modules-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            namedExport: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

it's a bit of a faff or kerfuffle but it is possible